# Jenkins gerrit trigger not reporting verified voting if there are any compilation errors

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit-trigger

When I do some code changes and push the code to Gerrit. Jenkins build gets triggered and we usually get verified voting +1 or -1 depending on the result on to the Gerrit UI for that change.

Currently, we observed that for any of the compilation errors it is not reporting on to the Gerrit. And this happens only for compilation errors, not for failing tests, failing git checkouts or other reasons that make a build fail.

Below I've mentioned the version details. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Gerrit Version: 2.14.2

Jenkins Version: 1.642.3

Gerrit-Trigger plugin: 2.18.3

Project: Java project

Build Tool: Maven

Regards

Sharieff.

Comment: Please add the compilation error message.

Answer (score 1):

That's intended for an "Unstable build" (i.e. compile/build errors but **not** a test error) in the default Gerrit-trigger configuration.

Take a look at your "Gerrit Reporting Values" for the project/default configuration.
If you want to use the "verify" label for unstable (i.e. compile errors) **and** failed (test errors) builds, configure the verify values like seen below.

(iirc the default configuration uses code-review = -1 for unstable, for this the used gerrit account needs the permission to submit a code-review label)

[image: Verify for unstable and failed builds]